# Loop an array and retain only elements that relate to a specific key with a qualifying value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, filter

I have this array :

```
(
  [id] => block_5df755210d30a
  [name] => acf/floorplans
  [data] => Array
  (
    [floorplans_0_valid_for_export] => 0
    [floorplans_0_title] => title 1
    [floorplans_0_house_area] => 40m²
    [floorplans_0_bedrooms] => 1
    [floorplans_1_valid_for_export] => 1
    [floorplans_1_title] => title xx
    [floorplans_1_house_area] => 90m²
    [floorplans_1_bedrooms] => 2
    [floorplans_2_valid_for_export] => 1
    [floorplans_2_title] => title 2
    [floorplans_2_house_area] => 50m²
    [floorplans_2_bedrooms] => 1
    [floorplans] => 3

  )
)
```

As we can see in the data, we have fields (`floorplans_X_valid_for_export`).
What I want to do is to get the data only when this field equal to `1`.

So from the given example, I want to keep only these fields:

```
[floorplans_1_valid_for_export] => 1
[floorplans_1_title] => title xx
[floorplans_1_house_area] => 90m²
[floorplans_1_bedrooms] => 2
[floorplans_2_valid_for_export] => 1
[floorplans_2_title] => title 2
[floorplans_2_house_area] => 50m²
[floorplans_2_bedrooms] => 1
```

Comment: in `floorplans_X_valid_for_export` is X always unique e.g. it can't be repeated?

Comment: When you ask a question, please do not merely "dump your requirements".  If you are a programmer, we expect to see your best failure.  In doing so, you prove that you are not using SO as a free coding service and volunteers may have an easier time of correcting a small portion of your script instead of crafting a whole new solution.  My SO philosophy does not permit me to upvote a question with no coding attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an odd schema, but it can be done by iterating through the array and searching for keys where "valid_for_export" equals 1, and then using another array of field "stubs" to get the associated items by a unique identifier of X in `floorplans_X_valid_for_export`

```
$array = [
    'floorplans_0_valid_for_export' => 0,
    'floorplans_0_title' => 'title 1',
    'floorplans_0_house_area' => '40m²',
    'floorplans_0_bedrooms' => 1,
    'floorplans_1_valid_for_export' => 1,
    'floorplans_1_title' => 'title xx',
    'floorplans_1_house_area' => '90m²',
    'floorplans_1_bedrooms' => '2',
    'floorplans_2_valid_for_export' => 1,
    'floorplans_2_title' => 'title 2',
    'floorplans_2_house_area' => '50m²',
    'floorplans_2_bedrooms' => 1,
    'floorplans' => 3
];


$stubs = [
     'floorplans_%s_valid_for_export',
     'floorplans_%s_title',
     'floorplans_%s_house_area',
     'floorplans_%s_bedrooms'
];

$newArr = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'valid_for_export') && $array[$key] == 1) {
        $intVal = filter_var($key, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        foreach ($stubs as $stub) {
            $search = sprintf($stub, $intVal);
            if (isset($array[$search])) {
                $newArr[$search] = $array[$search];
            } else {
                // key can't be found, generate one with null
                $newArr[$search] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
```

Working: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/23a225e3cefa2dc9cc97f53f1cbae0ea291672c0

Comment: This solution is pure poetry.  The only improvement I could suggest is some comments - even an experienced coder is going to have to think it through.  I particularly like the `$stub` / `sprintf`  combo.

Comment: There is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a parent loop to check that the number-specific `valid_for_export` value is non-empty -- since it is either 0 or non-zero.

If so, then just push all of the associated elements into the result array.

Some reasons that this answer is superior to the @Alex's answer are:

1. Alex's parent loop makes 13 iterations (and the same number of `strpos()` calls); mine makes just 3 (and only 3 calls of `empty()`).
2. `$array[$key]` is more simply written as `$value`.
3. Sanitizing the `$key` to extract the index/counter is more overhead than necessary as demonstrated in my answer.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UY1Wg))

```
$array = [
    'floorplans_0_valid_for_export' => 0,
    'floorplans_0_title' => 'title 1',
    'floorplans_0_house_area' => '40m²',
    'floorplans_0_bedrooms' => 1,
    'floorplans_1_valid_for_export' => 1,
    'floorplans_1_title' => 'title xx',
    'floorplans_1_house_area' => '90m²',
    'floorplans_1_bedrooms' => '2',
    'floorplans_2_valid_for_export' => 1,
    'floorplans_2_title' => 'title 2',
    'floorplans_2_house_area' => '50m²',
    'floorplans_2_bedrooms' => 1,
    'floorplans' => 3
];

$labels = ['valid_for_export', 'title', 'house_area', 'bedrooms'];

$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $array['floorplans']; ++$i) {
    if (!empty($array['floorplans_' . $i . '_valid_for_export'])) {
        foreach ($labels as $label) {
            $key = sprintf('floorplans_%s_%s', $i, $label);
            $result[$key] = $array[$key];
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'floorplans_1_valid_for_export' => 1,
  'floorplans_1_title' => 'title xx',
  'floorplans_1_house_area' => '90m²',
  'floorplans_1_bedrooms' => '2',
  'floorplans_2_valid_for_export' => 1,
  'floorplans_2_title' => 'title 2',
  'floorplans_2_house_area' => '50m²',
  'floorplans_2_bedrooms' => 1,
)
```

Comment: I literally answered a moment after the earlier answer was accepted.  I wish people would be more patient (or be willing to shift the tick) so that researchers could more easily find the best answer.

Comment: your answer is cleaner, however I would suggest verbatim checking if the value is equal to 1 and doing something like `$result[$key] = isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : null;` just to avoid potential errors. seems like this db schema isn't properly formatted so I would fully expect issues with OP's data that we aren't seeing

Comment: I don't see any evidence in the question that those concerns will occur.  I agree the structure of the incoming data is not ideal.

Comment: Understandable, but "undefined array key" errors are always sad when they can be easily avoided.

Comment: This is an "invented" concern.  Null coalescing would be my technique of choice if the threat was real.

Answer (score 0):

With that constructed data it might be hard (not impossble tho), hovewer i would suggest to change it to multidimensional arrays so you have something like:

```
[floorplans][0][valid_for_export] => 0
[floorplans][0][title] => title 1
[floorplans][0][house_area] => 40m²
[floorplans][0][bedrooms] => 1
[floorplans][1][valid_for_export] => 1
[floorplans][1][title] => title xx
[floorplans][1][house_area] => 90m²
```

**Rought sollution**

It is not the best approach, but it should work if you dont need anything fancy, and know that structure of data wont change in future

```
$keys = [];
$for($i=0;$i<$array['floorplans'];++$i) {
    if(isset($array['floorplans_'.$i.'_valid_for_export']) && $array['floorplans_'.$i.'_valid_for_export']===1) {
        $keys[] = $i;
    }
}

print_r($keys);
```

Comment: Here is the problem is that i cannot change the structure of it.

Comment: @AmjadKhalil i added rought solution, it is not pretty but should do the job

Comment: It is appropriate advice to recommend re-structure the incoming data -- but that should be a comment under the question.  The second snippet does not provide the desired output.  This is not a good answer.